# How to make sub div elements automatically adjust it's width, when width of main div is increased?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two div elements. One div is for menu on the left side and another div for the main content on the right side. Content div has three sub-div elements which is made like three adjacent columns.

I have a toggle button in the page. when I click toggle button menu div is hidden and main content div is automatically expanded to cover the whole page. But the problem is the three sub-div elements like columns is not adjusting the width when main content div size is increased even though I use min-width css for sub divs.

my css 
for columns(same for all the three columns):

```
.column1 { min-width: 360px; float: left; padding-bottom: 115px; }
```

for main content

```
#content{ background-color:#EEEEEE; height:600px; min-width:1100px; float:left;}
```

Comment: does the 3 div inside has the properte `width:100%`

Comment: @Atal Shrivastava do u want css code alone?

Comment: @audre7 adding width:100% to columns, makes the column appear outside the main content div. That is, each column is trying to fill the whole main content area. So, when one column fills main content area, remaining two columns appear outside the main content div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the width in percent

```
.sub-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

if you need space in between then

```
.sub-div {
  width: 30%;
  margin:3.33%;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use width as Percent for sub-div

```
sub-div{width:25%)
```